# SPO Search Item Display Template Boolean Property Mapping

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, display-template

On Sharepoint Online, I am trying to build a grid-view for Search Center search results. I am unable to extract the values of either OWSBOOL or OWSCHCS properties.

I have added ManagedPropertyMappings for my custom properties:

```
    'Filename':'Filename',
    ...
    'ImageOWSBOOL':'ImageOWSBOOL',
    ...
    'ECStatusOWSCHCS':'ECStatusOWSCHCS'
```

I have modified a stock Item_Display template:

```
        <div style="min-width:60px;width:60px;max-width:60px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
            _#=ctx.CurrentItem.ImageOWSBOOL=#_
        </div>
        ...
        <div style="min-width:100px;width:100px;max-width:100px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
            _#=formatProperties(ctx.CurrentItem.ECStatusOWSCHCS)=#_
        </div>
```

Other custom properties are displayed in the search results, but I don't know how to parse the values out of these two properties (the 'No' value in the Image column is the result of an if(ctx.CurrentItem.ImageOWSBOOL===1) else ('No') call:

[image]

So, does anyone have the decoder ring to decypher these properties?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in this custom boolean property were either "True 1" or "False 0".

IE11 doesn't support string.includes() (although IE12/Edge does).

So, I parsed the value of my custom property named ImageOWSBOOL as follows:

if (ctx.CurrentItem.ImageOWSBOOL.indexOf("True")!=-1) { Do Stuff } else { Do Other Stuff}

I haven't solved the OWSCHCS property parsing yet...

Thx!